# I need to copy all jpg files from a directory in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to copy all the jpg files from a directory to another directory. How do i make to copy all files finishing in jpg?

Answer (score 0):

```
cp {SourceDirectory}/*.jpg {DestinationDirectory}/.
```

Where *{directory}* is your **from** and **to** directories.

You could also

```
cd {SourceDirectory}
cp *.jpg {DestinationDirectory}/.
```

Note that Linux is case sensitive so ***.jpg** is different than ***.JPG** .

It's also possible to recurse through subdirectories with a **-r** parameter, but be careful with that.